# Не выводятся все поля из модели в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Например во вьюхе вывожу пользователей так:

```
  <?php
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="index.php?r=users%2Fedit&id=<?= $user->getId() ?>&page=1" ><?= $user->username ?></a></td>
                <td><?= $user->firstname ?></td>
                <td><?= $user->lastname ?></td>
                <td><?= $sexes[$user->sex] ?></td>
                <td><?= $user->email ?></td>
                <td><?= $user->created ?></td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                        'id' => 'delete-user-form',
                        'action' => 'index.php?r=users%2Fdelete&id=' . $user->getId()
                    ]) ?>
                    <?= $form->field($user, 'id')->hiddenInput()->label(false) ?>
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm']) ?>
                    <?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
    <?php
            }
?>
```

Но поле username пустое, id тоже пустое. Что надо сделать?
Запрос в контроллере:

```
        $rows = User::find()
        ->select(['id', 'username', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'sex', 'email', 'date_format(created, \'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i\') as created'])
        ->all();
```

Comment: Напишите как делаете запрос в моделе. Проблема в нем.

Answer (score 0):

select не имеет смысла в activeQuery, если только это не подзапрос, в модели все равно окажутся все поля.

У вас проблема в дубликатах id формы и именах полей.

на пример так.(могу ошибаться на счет расположения квадратных скобок, но они однозначно нужны)

```
<?= $form->field($user, '**[]**id')->hiddenInput()->label(false) ?>
```

и вот так

```
 $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                        'id' => 'delete-user-form-'.$user->id,
                        'action' => 'index.php?r=users%2Fdelete&id=' . $user->getId()
                    ]) ?>
```